# Typeorm getMany() doesn't return related entity

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i have a doubt with Typeorm getMany() function.
I have this code

```
   const res = await this.repo
  .createQueryBuilder('result')
  .leftJoinAndSelect(
    UserAnag,
    'useranag',
    'useranag.playerId = result.playerId',
  )
  .where('result.server = :idServer', { idServer: serverId })
  .andWhere('result.raceId = :idRace', { idRace: raceId })
  .getMany();
```

This code return only the result entity, not the useranag entity.
If i change with getRawMany() returns all the data i need, but in raw format not entity object like.

It return as getRawMany() function expect

```
   result.id,
   result.position,
   useranag.id,
   useranag.name
```

etc

instead i expected with getMany() function

```
   result.id,
   result.position,
   useranag: {
      id: xx,
      name: yyy
   }
```

I can manually recreate the object but i want understand wher's the problem.
My **useranag** and **result** entity have a **join field playerId** but ther's no relation mapped in entity.

On Typeorm manual demonstrate that i can user leftjoinAndSelect also for non related entity and with getMany() function

These are my Entity that i join

```
@Entity()
export class Results {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;
@Column()
position: number;
@Column()
laps: number;
@Column({ type: 'time', precision: 3 })
bestLaps: Date;
@Column({ type: 'time', precision: 3 })
gap: Date;
@Column()
penalties: number;
@Column()
server: number;
@Column()
playerId: string;

@ManyToOne(() => Cars, (cars) => cars.result)
car: Cars;
@ManyToOne(
() => Competitionraces,
(competitionRaces) => competitionRaces.result,
)
race: Competitionraces;
}
```

and these are the other entity to join with , useranag

```
@Entity()
export class UserAnag {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;
@Column()
name: string;
@Column()
surname: string;
@Column()
psn: string;
@Column()
discord: string;
@Column()
drivernumber: number;
@Column()
playerId: number;

@OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.useranag, {
onDelete: 'CASCADE',
})
@JoinColumn()
user: User;

@ManyToOne(() => Discord, (useranag) => useranag.siglaTeam)
discordTeam: Discord;
}
```

Comment: You have to have the relation entity as a field in your entity. Otherwise when TypeOrm creates instances of your entity class, it has no way of identifying that it should attach the relation to the entity. In Typescript point of view, the type won't match as well. Where did you see in TypeOrm manual that it is not required to have the relation entity?

Comment: [link](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#joining-any-entity-or-table) at this link it says : "You can join not only relations, but also other unrelated entities or tables"
In my case, the field of relation does not exist initially on every member of entity so i can't define the relation

Comment: I haven't come up with your specific use case. However, here `unrelated` entities mean no foreign key reference on either side. For example `Result` entity should have a field called `useranag` but doesn't necessarily have relationship decorators. Without the proper field defined in the class, it would be wrong for TypeOrm to inject that field into a class instance (going against Typescript). If you still can't make this work, you can put your entity class code here in the question.

Comment: Oh, i understand! is Enough to have the right field of the right type without any relationship. I will try! Thank you so much.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan not working... these are my entities before adding field

Comment: Did you try adding `useranag?: UserAnag` property in `Results` class? (Also, it is hard to read your code without proper indentation)

Comment: I will try to add useranag?: UserAnag with @Column decorator but obviously make an error because it want to have this field on database. 
I use the wrong decorator on entity?

Comment: No ned to add a decorator. Simply add the field

Comment: Not working ...

Comment: Find a solution. Is not leftjoinandselect but leftjoinandmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem and i will show the best solution i can find for this problem:

On my Entity i create this field

```
@ManyToOne(() => UserAnag, (useranag) => useranag.results, {
createForeignKeyConstraints: false,
})
@JoinColumn({ name: 'playerId', referencedColumnName: 'playerId' })
useranag: UserAnag;
```

with **createForeignKeyConstraints: false** this does not create the foreign key column on my database but create the join relation.

Then on my query, instead of querybuilder, i use classic find()

```
return await this.repo.find({
  relations: { car: true, useranag: true },
});
```